# CSS Priority problems

Tags: html, css

I have a question related to the CSS priority.

If I have something like this:

```
<div id="reportBox">
    <p id="reportBoxTitle">MAIN REPORT</p>
    <p id="reportBoxContent">Promoting Investment in Agriculture</p>
</div>
```

And then I have the following CSS settings:

```
#reportBox p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #004673; 
}

#reportBoxTitle{
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

In this way the text **Promoting Investment in Agriculture** that is into **reportBoxTitle** div still have a size of 12px and not 18px as specified by **#reportBoxTitle** settings.

It seems that the general **#reportBox p** settings have the priority on the specific **#reportBoxTitle** settings.

Is it a normal behavior?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: `In this way the text "Promoting Investment in Agriculture" that is into reportBoxTitle div` this statement is not true, that text is not in a `div#reportBoxTitle`.

Comment: It is not in a `<p>` with and `id` of `ReportBoxTitle` either, its in a `p` with the `ID` of `reportBoxContent`, and you don't define a style for this `p`, so it inherits the properties of its parent element. So to answer your question, this is normal behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's normal: the [**specificity**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) for the first selector is higher (`id` + `tag`) than for the the second one (just `id`), so the rules written there prevail.

The easiest way to solve it is to add a tag to the second selector as well, making specificity of the selectors the same so that the last one can 'win' now:

```
p#reportBoxTitle {
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/F4rfh/).

But actually, I don't understand why you've used `<p>` here instead of `<hN>` selector: this paragraph is clearly a header of the report, and should not only be styled, but also marked in HTML accordingly. For example:

```
<div id="reportBox">
    <h3 id="reportBoxTitle">MAIN REPORT</h3>
    <p id="reportBoxContent">Promoting Investment in Agriculture</p>
</div>
```

Now you can use the fact that all the properties you're setting in `#reportBox` currently are inherited by its children, and rewrite CSS as follows:

```
#reportBox {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #004673; 
}

#reportBox h3{
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jTC3b/).

Answer (score 0):

All info about CSS specificity nightmare here :D
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

[image]

Try this :

```
#reportBox p#reportBoxTitle{
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```